# Android transtion to CollapsingToolbarLayout from textview

Tags: android, view, toolbar, transition

I have a problem, I'm trying to make a scene transition between two activities.

In activity A, I have a TextView.

In activity B, I have a CollapsingToolbarLayout.

When I click in a button i activity A, I want to make a scene to activity B, which the textview go to the CollapsingToolbarLayout title. I do the following in Activity A:

```
ActivityOptionsCompat options =     
ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,textView, "title");
ActivityCompat.startActivity((AppCompatActivity)context, intent, options.toBundle());
```

And in ActivityB:
Layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/logo2"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
.
.
.
```

And Activity (onCreate method):

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title");
ViewCompat.setTransitionName(toolbar,"title");
```

But it don't work, it doesn't do the transition properly. Any ideas?